# No easy way to properly label sub-aspects of claims

Tags: feature-request

A key feature of reading patents is understanding the structure of the claims. Patents usually have between 10 and 30 numbered claims with most of them making reference, by number, to other claims. Separately, within a claim there are almost always a list of elements. Some claim authors label them a), b) etc. Some just start a new line and indent for the start of each element. Understanding claims is complicated and the visual breakout of the elements of claims is key to not getting lost.

Our template for our most on-topic questions requires the OP to cut and paste "claim 1" from the patent or patent application in question. Claim 1 is usually the broadest representation of what the applicant claims as theirs. In our template the elements get made into a list. Fine, but it is a numbered list. It would be better if the template encouraged claim elements to be labeled (if at all): a) b) c) rather than 1. 2. 3. It is already unclear to people that all elements of a claim are required to infringe that claim. Adding arabic numerals within an aribic numeral numbered claim doesn't help to clarify, in my view, especially in an otherwise word-for-word "quote" of the claim. Since the real claim numbering is central to unwinding the claim coverage it is confusing to have number elements.

I have explicitly labeled elements alphabetically by hand in several posts. It would be a big improvement if a), b) were provided as a list format. The other option would be to have claims pasted in some way that preserved them exactly as they appear in the copied text at google/patents